# ScrollMagic with each loop and $(this).find

Tags: jquery, loops, each, scrollmagic

I am trying to animate several span elements inside my h1-tags with ScrollMagic.

The goal is to loop through every h1 (except the first one), find the spans with .msk classes and add another class (.is-visible) to their children.

I already set up an each loop, but i don't know how to correctly combine $(this) with another selector.

My code looks like this:

```
$('h1:not(:first)').each(function() {

 var msk = $(this).find('.msk span');
 console.log(msk);

 var h1Scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: this,
  triggerHook: 0.7,
  reverse: false,
 })
 .addIndicators({
   name: "H1"
 })
 .setClassToggle(msk, 'is-visible')
 .addTo(controller)
});
```

I already did some research, but i still can't figure out how it works.

Comment: Did you look at my answer?

Comment: @xxxmatko sorry totally forgot to reply. It just worked out. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation the first argument of the `setClassToggle` function should be **A Selector targeting one or more elements or a DOM object that is supposed to be modified.**

But when you call `var msk = $(this).find('.msk span');` you will have and jQuery object stored in the `msk` variable. So this should be an invalid call

`.setClassToggle(msk, 'is-visible')`

Try to call this instead

`.setClassToggle(msk[0], 'is-visible')`

it will give you access to the pure DOM element selected by the jQuery.

Comment: sorry it might be unclear, but i want to select all spans (childrens) of the parent span element with .msk class. I think the problem is the wrong combination with .setClassToggle method and this inside.